# How to stop loading panel when validating jquery validations

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery validation in my javascript files to validate that my ValidationMessageFor will fire if there is an issue client side.

When this start, a loading panel starts. I am trying to STOP the loading panel IF an validation message is displayed etc.

I went into the jquery.validate.obstruive.js file and added the code below, but it is not firing or hitting the code:

```
function onError(error, inputElement) {  // 'this' is the form element
    var container = $(this).find("[data-valmsg-for='" + escapeAttributeValue(inputElement[0].name) + "']"),
        replaceAttrValue = container.attr("data-valmsg-replace"),
        replace = replaceAttrValue ? $.parseJSON(replaceAttrValue) !== false : null;

    container.removeClass("field-validation-valid").addClass("field-validation-error");
    error.data("unobtrusiveContainer", container);

    if (replace) {
        container.empty();
        error.removeClass("input-validation-error").appendTo(container);
        // Added to turn off loading indicator if there is an error...
        $(".loadingIndicator").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
    else {
        error.hide();
    }
}
```

Here is the code that I use to stop the loading panel:

```
  // Added to turn off loading indicator if there is an error...
        $(".loadingIndicator").css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

I expect that once the jquery.validate... code fires and sees that I have a required filled not set or I am entering alpha characters in a number text field, then I want the loading panel to stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help.

My code worked fine with how I had it set up.

At one point we were going to use a check box from Dev Express.

That check box was removed, but a reference to loading the Dev Express scripts was not.

The jquery unobtrusive validation was being fired from the Dev Express file instead of our local one - where I changed the code to stop the loading panel if a validation client side was displayed etc.

Everything is working fine now.

Hopefully this will help someone.